# vb.net arithmetic operation resulted in overflow

Tags: vb.net, math

I have a texbox in which i introduce a number, number example is 1860812430041.
The code sections where i call that textbox is:

```
Convert.ToDouble(cnptxt.Text)
Dim cnpp As Double
cnpp = Val(cnptxt.Text)
Dim cnp As Double
If Me.ClientiTableAdapter.InsertQueryClienti(nume, 
      prenume, cnp, varsta, adresa, localitate, 
      datatxt.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), starecivila, 
      numarcopii, venittxt.Text, tipcreditales, rezultat) Then
            MsgBox("Adaugat cu succes in baza de date!")
```

When running the application i get the error "Arithmetic operation resulted into overflow" and it lightens the If condition.
The whole code is

```
 Convert.ToDouble(cnptxt.Text)
        Convert.ToInt32(numarcopiitxt.Text)
        Convert.ToInt32(venittxt.Text)

        Dim cnpp As Double
        cnpp = Val(cnptxt.Text)
        Dim nrcopii As Integer
        nrcopii = Val(numarcopiitxt.Text)

        Dim nume As String

        Dim prenume As String
        Dim cnp As Double
        Dim varsta As Integer
        Dim adresa As String
        Dim localitate As String
        Dim starecivila As String
        Dim numarcopii As Integer
        Dim data As Date = datatxt.Value.Date
        Dim venit As Integer
        Dim tipcreditales As String
        Dim rezultat As String




        nume = numetxt.Text
        prenume = prenumetxt.Text
        cnp = cnpp
        varsta = varstatxt.Text
        adresa = adresatxt.Text
        localitate = localitatetxt.Text
        starecivila = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
        numarcopii = numarcopiitxt.Text
        tipcreditales = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        rezultat = rezultattxt.Text
        venit = venittxt.Text
        data = datatxt.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")


        If Me.ClientiTableAdapter.InsertQueryClienti(nume, prenume, cnp, varsta, adresa, localitate, datatxt.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), starecivila, numarcopii, venittxt.Text, tipcreditales, rezultat) Then
            MsgBox("Adaugat cu succes in baza de date!")
        End If
```

The DB table where i'm trying to insert is has NUMBER set as accepted.

Comment: most likely you are doing something with that numeral incorrectly (such as trying to treat it as an integer) in a part of the code you didnt show

Comment: You show `cnpp = Val(cnptxt.Text)`, but your `InsertQueryClienti` uses `cnp`, which is never initialized. Why are you assigning a value to a variable you don't use, and using a variable to which you never assign a value? (You also do a `Convert.ToDouble(cnptxt.Text)` which you then throw away; you need to assign the result of that `Convert` to a variable. Your code is non-functional in a couple of ways.)

Comment: i'm trying to learn vb.net on my own, that's why i have so many mistakes in my code. What is the solution your are proposing?

Comment: @user3801004: You should start by watching a professional course or two on pluralsight.

Comment: You might be doing to much at the same time. Try to learn how to use the debugger and write only one line at a time and compile to see what it does.

Comment: Well, as the error you're getting comes from `InsertQueryClienti`, and we don't know what that does, my suggestion? Copy down the values of all of the variables that you pass into it, get the SQL that's being run during the insert operation, and run the query in SQL Server or Access, plugging in the values you copied from the variables, and see what the actual problem is with the query. (You didn't include that in either your original code or the new code you edited to include, and we don't have the values of all of the textbox controls or your database to use to debug it for you.)

Comment: @KenWhite : You were right. I tried to manually introduce the variables in the access DB and when i reached the cnp field it triggered an error. It was set as number but with field size long int, after changing it to double everything went fine. Thank you very much for your help, and have a little mercy for the newbies. Cheers!